# How much water can an object raise after its fall?

Tags: potential-energy, collision

Suppose that there is a small object (e.g. hand sized) with volume $V$ and mass $m$ that falls into a water container from a height $h_0$ and with initial velocity $v_0$. Is there a way to compute the height $h_{\mathrm{water}}$ that the water will reach after the object impacts on it? What I mean is something like this: [High Speed Imaging: Object dropping into water](https://youtu.be/pLL6oseE5_U).

Comment: I have no idea how to edit this question to make it "better". I have no knowledge in fluid dynamics and I would not know where to start from. I can do an analysis based on potential and kinetic energy of the mass, but then I would not know how to proceed.

Comment: Relevant search term: [Worthington jet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-XNDM4eAn1U).

Comment: @user190081 You might read about our [reopening process for closed questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions). I suggest a discussion in [chat] or on [meta] rather than an appeal to an individual moderator.

Comment: It's good that user190081 decided to write a [meta post about the closing of this question.](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10842/reopen-request-question-about-water-splash-on-impact).

Comment: @JohnRennie I agree, my question is a duplicate of the one you linked. Thanks! I will carefully check the answer, I think it is useful. user190081: I read your question in the meta, I cannot comment since I do not have enough reputation. I read all the comments and I agree with all of you. Thank you very much for the help. I also think that DavidZ probably made a mistake, but that can happen, and I am glad that my question led to a positive and constructive discussion in the meta

Comment: I marked this question as a duplicate since that seemed to be pretty uncontroversial in the discussion on the meta question (and here).